# What adds lost health?

Tags: mafia-3

In Mafia 3 you have a health bar split up in parts. If a part gets shot down it won't regenerate. Now my question is what are the ways to add those health parts back.

I've noticed that when you take a medical cabinet you don't get any parts back. I've also noticed that when you finish a mission you get back healed to full. But are there any other ways to get health bars back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you interact with a health cabinet you pick up an adrenaline shot which will recover 2 bars of your health when used.

To use the shot, hold up on the D-pad on PS4 and I assume it's the same for Xbone. As noted in the Zozo's answer, the default key is 'C' on PC.

You can use these shots at anytime, usually to recover health during combat.

Edited to add: 
There is a first aid icon (small cross) in the bottom left hand corner of the screen which shows how many how many adrenaline shots you currently have.

Edited again: 
You can upgrade your shot to fully recover your health by getting Vito's income to $320,000.

Comment: Adrenaline shots can also be purchased from the Weapons Dealer.  It is under supplies.

Answer (score 3):

"I've noticed that when you take a medical cabinet you don't get any parts back". You are... half true here.

Indeed when you go to a cabinet you don't get health back, but you get an adrenaline shot. You can use that to replace health (C on pc by default and Colin provided an answer for PS4).

Also you can improve on Vito relation to get additional health bars.

Sidenote: you can add armor on top of it... apparently it absorbs a huge ammount of dmg and for some reason a car crash deducts from your armor before reducing your health (this is a bit of a glitch imo).